# Load an array of structs and then load it on an archive

Tags: c, struct

I have two programs, one to load the array of structs in archive.txt , and another to read archive.txt . The problem is that when i read the archive, a lot of symmbols appear at the end of the file.

The structs:

```
typedef struct{

    int dd;
    int mm;
    int aa;

} date;


typedef struct{

    char nya[30];
    char dni[9];
    date dat;

} student;
```

This is the program to load an array of structs to archive.txt

```
int main()
{

    student al[3]={{"Pedro","34434343",{11,11,2011}},{"Jose","23233233",{11,12,2003}},{"Ramon","23434334",{11,2,1002}}};

    FILE * pf = fopen("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\archive.txt","w");

    fwrite(al,sizeof(student)*3,3,pf);

    fclose(pf);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the program to read the archive.txt:

```
int main(){
    student alu;

    FILE * pf = fopen("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\archive.txt","r");

    while(!feof(pf)){

        fread(&alu,sizeof(student),1,pf);
        printf("%s\n",alu.nya);
        printf("%s\n",alu.dni);
        printf("%d %d %d\n",alu.dat.dd,alu.dat.mm,alu.dat.aa);
    }

    fclose(pf);

}
```

[image: This is the result of the program.]

Comment: `while(!feof(pf)){

        fread(&alu,sizeof(student),1,pf);` --> `while(fread(&alu,sizeof(student),1,pf) == 1);`  Who or what text suggested using `feof()`?

Comment: Why i can not use feof() ?

Comment: Be fair, first, Who or what text suggested using `feof()`?

Comment: I saw the code from a classmate, and i thought that it would work.....

Comment: Try testing the return value of `fread()` [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642853/load-an-array-of-structs-and-then-load-it-on-an-archive?noredirect=1#comment74337417_43642853) instead and see if that solves [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642853/load-an-array-of-structs-and-then-load-it-on-an-archive?noredirect=1#comment74334448_43642975)

Comment: Code can use `feof()`, and code can use `sqrt()`, but neither tells code if the next `fread()` will work.  Important to test the function return value of all input functions - saves debugging time.

Comment: So... what is the use of feof?

Comment: When a function like `fread()`, `fgetc()`, `fscanf()` indicate via its return value that  no data was read, code can use `feof()/ferror()` to determine why: end-of-file occurred or input error.  The point being `feof()` is true when input was attempted and there was no more - it reflects the past, not the future.  Did `fread()==1` solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642853/load-an-array-of-structs-and-then-load-it-on-an-archive?noredirect=1#comment74334448_43642975)?

Comment: yes! That resolved the problem.

Comment: this line: `fwrite(al,sizeof(student)*3,3,pf);` has a problem that it is trying to write nine(9) instances of `student` to the file.  the line should be: `if( 1 != fwrite( al, sizeof(student)*3, 1, pf ) ) { perror( "fwrite failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful,

Comment: NEVER use `while( !feof( .. ) )`  because it does not do what you are expecting.   Suggest: `while( 1 == fread(&alu,sizeof(student),1,pf) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing too much data:

```
fwrite(al,sizeof(student)*3,3,pf);
```

The second argument to `fwrite` specifies the size of *each* element, and the third specifies the number of elements.  You're doing double work by multiplying the size by 3 and giving a count of 3.  Do this instead:

```
fwrite(al,sizeof(student),3,pf);
```

Also, you could check the return value of `fopen`, `fwrite`, and `fread` to ensure they were successful.

Comment: It worked! but the lecture is repeating the las element :(